# How do I change the CollectionType on a service proxy generated with svcutil.exe?

Tags: wcf, svcutil.exe

Ok, so I have implemented my services, created a new WCF service website to host my services in IIS and used svcutil to export metadata to the .xsd and .wsdl  files. From these files I generated  the service proxy.cs and .config files and added them to the client.

One of my service operations returns a Generic List to the client though. I know how to change the CollectionType of the deserialized DataType by configuring the Service Reference when it has been added from visual studio (Add Service Reference), but how do I change (or set during the creation of the proxy with svcutil(?)) the CollectionType?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a switch `/collectionType:<type>` you can add to specify the type. See the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) for all the detail.